# Scrolling text has trail of pixels in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

If you go to http://connectforhealthco.com/news-events/enrollment-updates/ they have a scrolling text at the top of the page that leaves a trail of pixels behind it on the latest version of Chrome (v37).

They appear to just be using JavaScript to modify the inline style `left: 1100px;` steadily downward until it is off the screen and resets.

What could be causing this?

[image: Screenshot showing trailing pixels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is because Chrome 37.x enables `DirectWrite` font rendering system on Windows or OSX by default and it's not using Graphics Device Interface (GDI) to render text anymore.

Try applying `transform: translateZ(0);` to the ticker `div` that is scrolling and has the text (`div` with class `mtphr-dnt-tick`) and it's children, this will force Chrome to use GPU to render the output for those elements and it will eliminate the trails that you see.

Alternatively, to see how `DirectWrite` affects this, go to `Chrome://flags` and Enable `Disable DirectWrite Windows`, ofcourse this is just for your tests and you can't force your users to do this.

Comment: I am on OSX, but I assume the problem is the same. Applying `transform: translateZ(0);` to the `div` fixes it.

Comment: @Justin Great, I also updated the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such an issue on the exact same version of chrome
"37.0.2062.103 m"
Might be something caused on your side, not exactly sure about that but I thought that might be useful that it doesn't happen for me on the exact same version of chrome. Maybe some of your exensions? Not sure, just giving a heads-up that it's not caused by the browser itself. That might be useful and I unfrotunately can't post comments as my reputation is not above 50.